# PostgreSQL with NHibernate problem with LIKE and parameter

Tags: nhibernate, postgresql

I have a problem with PostgeSQL and NHibernate. I have tried HQL and Criteria and select returns nothing. I used log4net to get generated query, replaced parameters with value and query returns result, why is that? Is there a special configuration for Postgre or NHibernate? I even tried with lowering (lower(column) like lower(:param)) and no result.

```
HQL : return sess.CreateQuery("from VersFile e where e.ConfigId = :confId and lower(e.FolderPath) like lower(:path) and e.Type = :type and e.Statuss = :statuss and e.Tester != '' order by e.Sequence asc").SetString("path",path).SetInt32("type", fileType).SetInt32("confId", configId).SetInt32("statuss", recordStatuss).List<VersFile>();
```

FolderPath is character varying column

OR Criteria

```
return sess.CreateCriteria(typeof(VersFile)).Add(Expression.Eq("Type", fileType)).Add(Expression.Eq("Statuss", recordStatuss)).Add(Expression.Eq("ConfigId", configId)).Add(Expression.Like("FolderPath", path, MatchMode.Start)).Add(Expression.Not(Expression.Eq("Tester", ""))).Add(Expression.Not(Expression.Eq("Statuss", (int)RecordStatuss.Merged))).AddOrder(Order.Asc("Sequence")).List<VersFile>();
```

Generated query looks like

```
select .... from versfile versfile0_ where ( versfile0_.statuss!=99) and versfile0_.confId=:p0 and (lower(versfile0_.fpath) like lower(:p1)) order by versfile0_.sequen asc;:p0 = 1, :p1 = '\%MainVss\%WinGui\%'
```

I've removed useless parameters from query string

Comment: consider editing your post and formatting it as a code, unless you expect everyone to be cryptanalyst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the `'\%MainVss\%WinGui\%'` isn't quite valid in modern postgreses. It's either `E'\%MainVss\%WinGui\%'` or '%MainVss%WinGui%'. Which is equivalent to `'%MainVss%WinGui%'`, which is not necessarily what you want it to be.

Comment: Actually it have to be \MainVss\WinGui\% , but when I perform select using pgAdmin, the only correct value that returns result is \%MainVss\%WinGui\%, why? i don't know.

Comment: What you want in actual query is `E'\\MainVss\\WinGui\\%'`. You can, probably, omit `E` prefix, but that should lead to the warning. The way you got it to work in in pgadmin means basically '*<anything>*MainVss*<anything>*WinGui*<anything>*'. And backslashes match this anything, but what you really wanted to do is just double your backslashes. Plus you may need addition escaping in your source code which I lack knowledge of.

Comment: Yes, i'm searching for E'\\MainVss\\WinGui\\%', but i'm using NHibernate, all the data is inserted in tables by NHibernate. I don't have that problem on test db where i use SQLite.

Comment: Well, the thing is - in the code you posted there's a mention of weirdly formatted string, so clearly this is where the problem lies. Unfortunately, I can't help you further than this point.